# How to calculate flow matrix for an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to calculate the EarthmoversDistance for an image. I dont know how to calculate the FlowMatrix for an image or region.

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it'll be good for you: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22962-the-earth-mover-s-distance?focused=5110777&tab=function

Answer (score 0):

try using the fmincon function from matlab https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html
This enables you to give the objective as an anonymous function (@ operator). I copied you an example code from [source of example code](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/333446-linear-programming-involving-sum-of-element-wise-product-of-two-matrices)

```
 A = magic (3)
con = @constraints % we define a function file "constraints.m" that contains the constraints
min = @(B) -(sum(sum(A.*B))) % since all optimisation in Matlab can find minimum so we are trying to minimise the negetive of the objective.
a = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
lb = [];
ub = [];
x0 = zeros(3); % starting point for optimization
[sol, fval] = fmincon(min,x0,a,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,con) % This would give you 'B' and value of 'sum' (negetively minimised)
 % %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
 % the contents of the file "constraints.m" (kept in same folder) are as following:-
 function [c,ceq] = constraints(x)
 c = x*[1;2;3] - [51;62;37];
 ceq = [];
 end
 % [1;2;3] corresponds to 'c' in the question
 % [51;62;37] corresponds to 'd' in the question
 % imply Bc <= d  (in question its Bc < d (without equalto))
```

By the way, next time use a more specific text, provide sample code and try finding similiar meanings to your problem. Especially the last point has probably led to a lot of confusion, since adding the tag computer vision with a question about a flow matrix for images misleads the reader to think you are talking about optical flow (an important topic in computer vision).

Please don't forget to set the green checkmark. Good luck with your statistics!